# Ошибка при валидации модели AR(mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given)

Tags: yii

Привет всем.
Есть форма добавления проекта(проект это отдельно модель), в ней несколько textarea полей, например "Список сайтов"(сайт это отдельная модель, связь между проектом и сайтом - один-ко-многим, т.е. к одному проекту подвязано много сайтов), в каждое такое поле с новой строки записываются строки. А далее при сохранении модели я присваиваю POST данные моделе, произвожу валидацию, а далее пытаюсь сохранить эти данные. И когда начинаю сохранять данные по сайтам получаю вот такую ошибку при валидации - "mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given".
Часть кода из контроллера:

```
    if(isset($_POST['Project'])){
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Project'];
        if($model->validate()){
            $model->save();
            // преобразовываем в массив набор строк
            $competitors = explode(PHP_EOL,$model->competitors);
            foreach($competitors as $competitor){
                $competitor = new Competitor();
                $competitor->competitor_domen = $competitor;//$competitor - type - string
                $competitor->project_id = $model->id;
                $competitor->save();// вот здесь возникает ошибка - mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
            }
```

Помогите понять в чём ошибка и как её решить ?

Comment: но ведь ясно же сказано что вы пытаетесь узнать длину объекта, а надо длину строки.

Answer (score 1):

```
$competitor->competitor_domen = $competitor;//$competitor - type - string
```

это присваивается объект, а не строка, как определено строчкой выше.

На всякий случай, если ничего не получается, попробуйте изменить блок с **foreach** на такой:

```
foreach($competitors as $competitor_){
                $competitor = new Competitor();
                $competitor->competitor_domen = $competitor_;//$competitor_ - type - string
                $competitor->project_id = $model->id;
                $competitor->save();// вот здесь возникает ошибка - mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

            }
```

Comment: поробуйте какое-нть произвольное имя туда вставить, напр `"test"` вместо `$competitor`

Comment: Так а что тогда делать ? как мне решить данный вопрос ?

Comment: а вот это уже зависит от вашей глобальной задачи, если есть класс `Competitor`, то у него явно должны быть какие-то поля, вроде `$competior->name`. Просмотрите сам класс.

Comment: Пробовал - работает, если заменить какой-то строкой. Тогда решил явно указать тип данных для $competitor - как строка, но и это не помогло.

Comment: Ошибка возникает ни в методе save, а тогда когда вы объект присваиваете, про-**var_dump**'те тогда данные. Каждую отдельную переменную и посмотрите где у вас объект.

Comment: $competitor(строка) и $model->id(число) - никаких объектов нет.

Comment: Я обновил ответ.

Comment: Проблема была в совпадении имён переменных,$competitor = new Competitor() и foreach($competitors as $i=>$competitor){